# Turning a ListenableFuture<Iterable<A>> to Iterable<ListenableFuture<B>> through split and run

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, guava, future

I'm looking to find the best way to convert a `ListenableFuture<Iterable<A>>` into a sequence of individual `ListenableFutures`. This is the kind of method signature I'm looking for:

```
public <A, B> Iterable<ListenableFuture<B>> splitAndRun(
    final ListenableFuture<Iterable<A>> elements, 
    final Function<A, B> func, 
    final ListeningExecutorService executor
);
```

Clearly I could do with if I returned `ListenableFuture<Iterable<ListenableFuture<B>>>`, but I feel like I should be able to split and run this and maintain its asynchronicity.

Here's the code I have so far, but you will notice the nasty `.get()` at the end, which rather ruins things. Please excuse me if I've overcomplicated things.

```
public class CallableFunction<I, O> implements Callable<O>{
  private final I input;
  private final Function<I, O> func;

  public CallableFunction(I input, Function<I, O> func) {
    this.input = input;
    this.func = func;
  }

  @Override public O call() throws Exception {
    return func.apply(input);
  }
}

public <A, B> Iterable<ListenableFuture<B>> splitAndRun(
    final ListenableFuture<Iterable<A>> elements, 
    final Function<A, B> func, 
    final ListeningExecutorService executor
) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
  return Futures.transform(elements, 
      new Function<Iterable<A>, Iterable<ListenableFuture<B>>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<ListenableFuture<B>> apply(Iterable<A> input) {
      return Iterables.transform(input, new Function<A, ListenableFuture<B>>() {
        @Override
        public ListenableFuture<B> apply(A a) {
          return executor.submit(new CallableFunction<A, B>(a, func));
        }
      });
    }
  }, executor).get();
}
```

Comment: Consider Chris Povirk's second answer as the solution to your problem.  With some adaptation, it will only result in a single `get` of waiting on the combined future.  With Mairbek Khadikov's answer you will need to have at least 2 `get`s in your code.  In any case, +1 for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(alternative to [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071244/28465))

But what if the transformation is slow or if it might fail for some inputs but succeed for others? In that case, we want to transform each output individually. Plus, *we want to ensure that the transformation happens only once*. Our collection transformation methods do **not** make this guarantee. As a result, in your example code, every iteration over the output will submit new tasks to the executor, even though the previously submitted tasks may have already completed. For this reason, we recommend `Iterables.transform` and friends only when the transformation is lightweight. (Typically, if you're doing something heavyweight, your transformation function will throw a checked exception, which `Function` doesn't allow. Consider this a hint :) Your example, of course, happens not to trigger the hint.)

What does that all mean in code? Basically, we'll reverse the order of operations that I gave in my other answer. We'll convert from `Future<Iterable<A>>` to `Iterable<Future<A>>` first. *Then* we'll submit a separate task for each `A` to convert it to a `B`. For this latter step, we'll supply an `Executor` [so that the transformation doesn't block some innocent thread](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transform%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction%29). (We'll now need only `Futures.transform`, so I've static imported it.)

```
List<ListenableFuture<A>> individuals = newArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < knownSize; i++) {
  final int index = i;
  individuals.add(transform(input, new Function<List<A>, A>() {
    @Override
    public A apply(List<A> values) {
      return values.get(index);
    }
  }));
}

List<ListenableFuture<B>> result = newArrayList();
for (ListenableFuture<A> original : individuals) {
  result.add(transform(original, function, executor));
}
return result;
```

That's the idea, anyway. But my implementation is dumb. We can easily do both steps at the same time:

```
List<ListenableFuture<B>> result = newArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < knownSize; i++) {
  final int index = i;
  result.add(transform(input, new Function<List<A>, B>() {
    @Override
    public B apply(List<A> values) {
      return function.apply(values.get(index));
    }
  }, executor));
}
return result;
```

Because this makes n `Futures.transform` calls instead of 1 and because it uses a separate `Executor`, it's better than my other solution if the transformation is heavyweight and worse if it's lightweight. The other caveat remains: This will work only if you know how many outputs you'll have.

Comment: This is a nice solution as it has not explicate blocking. Unfortunately in practice it's no different to my original implementation as there is an implicate block in getting the first element of the list. This doesn't make the solution bad or wrong, I like it, but it has to wait for that initial list to become available.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, this is as close as you'll get to the 'right' answer so I might as well mark it as such. An implicate block that can happen later on is better than my explicate block that has to occur now.

Comment: ... although I did miss the 'knownSize' sneaked in there ;)

Comment: Yeah, I figured I could sneak it in here after mentioning it in my less popular answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15071244/28465 :) As I note there, if you don't have a `knownSize`, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

If you think of `ListenableFuture` as a box, in order to get something from that box you have to block the thread (call the `get` method).

Not sure that implementing `splitAndRun` method could benefit you in some way. You would still have one single asynchronous operation that returns `ListenableFuture<Iterable<A>>`.

Reverse operation of joining `Iterable<ListenableFuture<A>>` as a single `ListenableFuture<Iterable<A>>` could be useful, though. You might want to use it in case if you want to collect several asynchronous computation into a single one.

Comment: For the reverse operation, that would be [`Futures.allAsList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html).

Comment: Yeah, this is fair enough. I was hoping that Google might have some clever collection that works on futures and will iterate through them based on their completion state. Unfortunately that would be terrifying.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this. The first is transforming a `Future<Iterable<A>>` to a `Future<Iterable<B>>`. That can be accomplished by nesting `Futures.transform` and `Iterables.transform` (**if** the transformation is fast -- more on that in an alternative answer). Here's the code (though I've swapped out `Iterables.transform` for `Lists.transform`, which will require a `Future<List<A>>`, for reasons that I'll also explain later):

```
final ListenableFuture<List<B>> transformed =
    Futures.transform(input, new Function<List<A>, List<B>>() {
      @Override
      public List<B> apply(List<A> inputs) {
        return Lists.transform(inputs, function);
      }
    });
```

Now comes the conversion from `Future<Iterable<B>>` to `Iterable<Future<B>>`. As Mairbek said, this isn't possible in general: We can't know how many elements the output will have until we know how many the `Future` will return. If we do know the number of elements in the output, though, we can make it work. We'll apply another `Futures.transform`. (And that's why I used `List` above. Plain `Collection` could also work, but the code would be uglier.)

```
List<ListenableFuture<B>> result = newArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < knownSize; i++) {
  final int index = i;
  result.add(Futures.transform(transformed, new Function<List<B>, B>() {
    @Override
    public B apply(List<B> values) {
      return values.get(index);
    }
  }));
}
return result;
```

Of course, every `Future` in the list will complete at the same time -- only when the full input `Future` is done. That is, we can't get the results earlier; we can get them only in a different format (namely, individual `Future` instances instead of a bulk list). That's a necessary limitation of starting with a `Future<Iterable<A>>`.